# how to check if R is running using ps aux on Ubuntu/Mac?

Tags: r, macos, ubuntu

Of course, I can't just grep for "R" because that's not specific enough...so I try to find the binary with `which`

```
$ which R
/usr/bin/R
```

So then using this to grep,

```
$ ps aux | grep /usr/bin/R
```

only shows my own grep command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

`ps aux | grep /exec/R`

Answer (score 1):

You might try this:

```
ps aux | grep R\$
```

This will search for lines ending in `R`, which should find what you want.